# Tkinter : parent windows screen change

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm relatively new to Tkinter and I need help.

I have created a Connect database window when a button(login) is clicked from the parent window. The new window is the login.py(file). But it's not opening

connect database.py below;

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk 
import os 
import pickle 
import mysql.connector  as sql
from tkinter import messagebox
import login



def login1():
    host = host_entry.get()
    port = port_entry.get()
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    database="cars"

    spec=sql.connect(host=host,user=username,password=password,port=port)
    if spec.is_connected():
        messagebox.showinfo("Connected","Database connected Sucessfully")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Exists", "Database is already connected")
    spec.close()




root = Tk()
root.geometry("1067x600")
root.configure(background="black")
root.resizable(False, False) 
root.title("School Diaries")


#background image 
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="files\Sublime Light1.jpg")
lbl_bg = Label(root,image=bg)
lbl_bg.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

#Labels 
host_label = Label(root, text="Host Name ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 12, "bold"))
host_label.place(x=675, y=115)
host_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#host_entry.insert(0, "localhost")
host_entry.place(x=687, y=139, width=145)

port_label = Label(root, text="Port ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
port_label.place(x=675, y=190)
port_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#port_entry.insert(0, "3307")
port_entry.place(x=690, y=213, width=145)

username_label = Label(root, text="Username ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
username_label.place(x=675, y=265)
username_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#username_entry.insert(0, "root")
username_entry.place(x=687, y=287, width=145)

password_label = Label(root, text="Password ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
password_label.place(x=675, y=338)
password_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#password_entry.insert(0, "root")
password_entry.place(x=687, y=361, width=145)

#buttons
submit = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Pics\submit.png')
submit_button = Button(root, image=submit,font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"), relief=FLAT, activebackground="white",borderwidth=0, background="white", cursor="hand2",command=login1)
submit_button.place(x=655, y=440)

login = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Pics\login.png')
login_button = Button(root, image=login,font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"), relief=FLAT, activebackground="white",borderwidth=0, background="white", cursor="hand2",commmand=login)
login_button.place(x=785, y=442)


root.mainloop()
```

[image of connect database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22O8A.png)
login.py file below ;

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk 
import os 
import pickle 
import mysql.connector  as sql
from tkinter import messagebox
import user_inter 

def login():
    host = user_inter.host_entry.get()
    port = user_inter.port_entry.get()
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()


    spec=sql.connect(host=host,user=username,password=password,port=port)
    if spec.is_connected():
        messagebox.showinfo("Connected","Database connected Sucessfully")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Exists", "Failed")
    

    mycur=spec.cursor()
    mycur.execute()

    

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1067x600")
root.configure(background="black")
root.resizable(False, False) 
root.title("School Diaries")

#background
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="files\login.jpg")
lbl_bg = Label(root,image=bg)
lbl_bg.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)


#Labels
login_lbl = Label(root, text="Login", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("San Francisco", 45))
login_lbl.place(x=757,y=120)

username_label = Label(root, text="Username ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
username_label.place(x=675, y=190)
username_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#username_entry.insert(0, "root")
username_entry.place(x=695, y=215, width=190)

password_label = Label(root, text="Password ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
password_label.place(x=675, y=280)
password_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#password_entry.insert(0, "root")
password_entry.place(x=692, y=305, width=190)

login = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Pics\login.png')
login_button = Button(root, image=login,font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"), relief=FLAT, activebackground="white",borderwidth=0, background="white", cursor="hand2",command=login)
login_button.place(x=770, y=390)

root.mainloop()
```

[image of login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkPnf.png)

PS ; connect database.py is mentioned in the code as user_intern.py

0

now my doubt is ;
I have created a login.py page using tkinter and I have created a connect database.py page also, so my doubt is I have a button called login in connect database window, now the how to give argument such as if I click the login button the screen shd change to my login.py screen .....hope u understand my doubt

when I click login the login.py shd execute in the parent window itself

Thanks,

any edits in code to get my output is welcomed
when i click login in connect database the login windows shd open in parent window itself

Comment: Your first mistake, you are using two roots. The main loop needs to be just one and it should be in the main py file. 
Also you imported both in each other. This is another mistake. You should import the calling file into your main file.

Comment: You have overwritten `login` by an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @ablmmcu in comment, tkinter only has 1 root, and it should be in main program
the other point is, i suggest using `tkinter.TopLevel()` and use it as a window to your database when you press `login` button and it succeed at logging in.
more info about `TopLevel`:

```
Toplevel widgets work as windows that are directly managed by the window manager. They do not necessarily have a parent widget on top of them.

Your application can use any number of top-level windows.
```

source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm

on a side note : you place `TopLevel` windows inside the root.